# How to MATCH names which starting letters are defined in an interval

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a movie dataset, which contains name of Directors and actresses. I want to catch all actresses names which start with letters between B to J. Except using 'OR'  `MATCH (a:ACTOR)-[:PLAYED]-> (:MOVIE) WHERE a.Name STRATS WITH 'B' OR a.Name STARTS WITH 'C' ...`, is there any more sophisticated way to do so?

I appreciate any suggestion with this matter.

Comment: You can use `IN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Cypher Regular expressions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#query-where-regex)

```
MATCH (a:ACTOR)-[:PLAYED]->(:MOVIE)
WHERE  toLower(a.name) =~ '[b-j].*'
RETURN a
```

Checking for all names that start with a character between b and j. Wild card at the end matches all suffixes.

You could also use IN, but you would have to supply the entire list of characters to match in this case:

```
MATCH (a:ACTOR)-[:PLAYED]->(:MOVIE)
WHERE  left(toLower(n.name),1) in ['b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
RETURN n.name
```

I have used [`toLower`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/string/#functions-tolower) in both cases to ensure the match is case insensitive.
In the second method, I am using the [`left`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/string/#functions-left) function to get the name's first character and checking if it is in the given list.
A [`Starts With`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#match-string-start) operator exists. But it doesn't allow matching against a list (IN).

Comment: dear Thennan, Thank you very much for your kind help. I appreciate that.

Comment: You are welcome. If the solution worked for you, please mark it as accepted and upvote it.